# why does this accept any username as long as password is correct

Tags: python

```
username = input("Welcome, please enter your username.")
password = input("Please enter your password.")

if username != "tony" and password != "password123":
  print("Access Denied.")

else:
  print("Welcome to the jungle")
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. It should be `or`, not `and`.

Comment: This is really something you can simply think through with pen and paper…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will try to make you understand by AND gate.

| **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** | **E** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **username** | **password** | **username!=Tony** | **password!=password123** | **Colmn_C AND Colmn_D(Access denied)** |
| Tony | password123 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Hulk | Password123 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Tony | xyz | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| Hulk | xyz | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

So you can see ,why Access is denied only when both are incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Change the test to:

```
if username != "tony" or password != "password123":
```

or turn the whole thing around:

```
if username == "tony" and password == "password123":
  print("Welcome to the jungle")    
else:
  print("Access Denied.")
```

That (IMO) makes it more clear both the username and the password need to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Good news, your code is written correctly!.
Bad news, your code is not doing what **you** want.

Try to read your conditional out load.

Your computer: 'if the user name is not "tony" **and** the password is not "password123," I should deny access.
Everything else I should accept.'
That means, when **only one** of them is wrong, it is ok!

Answer (score 0):

just change the statements or change the condition AND with OR

**solution1**

```
username = input("Welcome, please enter your username.")
password = input("Please enter your password.")
if username != "tony" or password != "password123":
  print("Access Denied.")
else:
  print("Welcome to the jungle")
```

**solution2**

```
username = input("Welcome, please enter your username.")
password = input("Please enter your password.")
if username != "tony" and password != "password123":
   print("Welcome to the jungle")
else:
   print("Access Denied.")
```